# call ajax function from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Sorry if this question makes no sense, I am still trying to understand ajax, JavaScript and jQuery. So here is my question.

This is my javascript code:

```
if (colorToCheck == gup("Player1")) {
    document.getElementById('win').innerHTML=player1+" wins";
    //add ajax call to update my json file
    redScore += 1
} else if (colorToCheck == gup("Player2")) {
    document.getElementById('win').innerHTML=player2+" wins";
    //add ajax call to update my json file
    blackScore += 1
}
```

So I want to call ajax from this block. I searched the net, but didn't get my answer. Thanks in advance. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery.ajax

Comment: What troubles are you having with $.ajax()?

Comment: you searched the net and didn't get an answer? the entire world is using ajax and jquery. there are tutorials and examples everywhere.

Comment: @Ohgogwhy Thanks for replying..So I can straight away add this function here $.ajax()??

Comment: @Timmerz I have a javascript code, and I wanted to use ajax in between..I know javascript and ajax,but wanted to combine both..That is my question..And I didn't know how..Anyway thanks for taking the time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "home.aspx", //you can call any function you want to execute in this url
  data: datastring,
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "This is ajax call:" + msg );
           // some code to exec on success
    }
 });
```

This is a sample ajax call..
If you are looking specifically for JSON then go through this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: oh thank you..I didn't know we could do this..Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:

```
$('#win').html(colorToCheck == gup("Player1") ? player1:player2 + " wins");

if (colorToCheck == gup("Player1")) 
   redScore += 1
else if (colorToCheck == gup("Player2")) 
  blackScore += 1

$.post("update-score.php", { player: x, score: y } );
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a good answer here. I just wanted to make sure you knew to include the JQuery library in your page header. You can use a Google hosted version of the library if you don't want to download it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

More libraries available at...

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

JQuery Tutorial

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

AJAX Introduction

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Blog

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/15-resources-to-get-you-started-with-jquery-from-scratch/

YouTube is a great place to learn more as well.

Good luck!